# Nivo slider shows part of the second image

Tags: slider, nivo-slider

Can you please help me to solve this problem? When I use Internet Explorer to view my website the slider shows part of the second image on the lower side, hiding the navigation bullets and the slider doesn't slide.

Here's the link for my test blog (use internet explorer):

http://joerencontenz.comoj.com/

Thank you.

**slide.php**

> /js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js">  /*/ jQuery(window).load(function() {
>     $('#slider').nivoSlider({       effect:'fade', //Specify sets like:
>   'fold,fade,sliceDown'         slices:20,      animSpeed:900,      pauseTime:4000,
>         startSlide:0, //Set starting Slide (0 index)        directionNav:false,
>   //Next & Prev         directionNavHide:false, //Only show on hover
>         controlNav:true, //1,2,3...
>           controlNavThumbs:false, //Use thumbnails for Control Nav
>           controlNavThumbsFromRel:false, //Use image rel for thumbs         keyboardNav:true, //Use left & right arrows         pauseOnHover:true,
>   //Stop animation while hovering       manualAdvance:false, //Force manual
>   transitions       captionOpacity:0.8 //Universal caption opacity  }); });*
>
> /]]>/    have_posts()) :
>   $my_query->the_post();$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?> ">ID,
>   'slide', $single = true); ?>" alt="" title=" 
>   " />

**slide.css**

```
/*
 * jQuery Nivo Slider v2.1
 * http://nivo.dev7studios.com
 *
 * Copyright 2010, Gilbert Pellegrom
 * Free to use and abuse under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *
 * March 2010
 */
#sliderw {
  height: 465px; /*385 default*/
  width:938px;
  padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  background: url(../images/sliderbg.png) no-repeat;
  margin: 0px auto 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#slider {
    position:relative;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 938px;
    height: 385px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
#slider .desc {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0px;
    padding:0;
    color:#fff !important;
    display: block;
}
.tit {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #f8bc12;
}
/* The Nivo Slider styles */
.nivoSlider {
    position:relative;
}
.nivoSlider img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
/* If an image is wrapped in a link */
.nivoSlider a.nivo-imageLink {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    z-index:60;
    display:none;
}
/* The slices in the Slider */
.nivo-slice {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:50;
    height:100%;
}
/* Caption styles */
.nivo-caption {
    position:absolute;
    left:-10px;
    background:#000;
    opacity:0.8; /* Overridden by captionOpacity setting */
    width: 920px !important;
    z-index:89;
    bottom: -10px;
    padding: 10px 20px 15px;
}
.nivo-caption p {
    padding:5px;
    margin:0;
    color: #000 !important;
}
.nivo-caption a {
    display:inline !important;
}
.nivo-html-caption {
    display:none;
}
/* Control nav styles (e.g. 1,2,3...) */
.nivo-controlNav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50px;
  left: 45%;
}
.nivo-controlNav a {
    position:relative;
    z-index:99;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-indent: -9999;
    background: url(../images/nivobutton.png) no-repeat;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 13px;
    margin-right: 7px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 13px;
}
.nivo-controlNav a.active {
    background: url(../images/nivobutton.png) no-repeat scroll right;
}
.sepsl {
  background: url(../images/sep.gif) repeat-x scroll bottom;
  height: 2px;
  clear: both;
  width: 904px;
  margin: 0 0 15px 24px;
}
```

Comment: can;t post the code...

Comment: Hi! I achieved to identify what was causing the problem with the slider in Internet Explorer 9 and I managed to resolve it. It was an add-on I had previously installed by mistake that was causing the problem. I had uninstalled it a long time ago but it was still active and I didn’t notice it. The name of this add-on is “PutLockerDownloader” or “smartdownloader Class” (company – Terra Firma Internet Consulting LTD). Now the slider works flawlessly!!!